# How to check values from query using DAO

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

I have this app that has a start tutorial and I am saving in room database if the user already saw the tutorial. For that I save the data when the user finishes the tutorial and do a query in the onCreateMethod of the TutorialActivity to see if I skip to other activity. My DAO as two methods, one to insert and another to load. My load method(what I want to ask) has the following code:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM tutorial LIMIT 1")
    fun load(): Single<TutorialEntity>

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun insert(userEntity: TutorialEntity): Single<Long>
```

My entity:

```
@Entity(tableName = "tutorial")
class TutorialEntity (

    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "as_seen_tutorial")
    val asSeenTutorial: Long

)
```

This is my tutorial activity:

Note: I use dagger to inject the tutorialDao(not important here)

```
//here is where I check if the value is already 1 to skip
    onCreate(){
    val load = tutorialDao.load()
    if(load.? contains 1) -> This is my doubt {      
      //OBJECTIVE: does not show and skips to other activity   
   } 
 }

//here is where I insert the flag into the database
fun showTutorial(){
  val entity = TutorialEntity(1)
  tutorialDao.insert(entity)
}
```

I wanted to know how can I check if the value that cames from the select query is one

Answer (score 1):

Well. I don't know if i understand you well but i had some questions before respond your doubt.

Why are you using a Single? (You are going to receive a NPE) (https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/single.html)

I recommend you to use just the class as nullable, so just check your variable for

```
if (load?.asSeenTutorial == 1) {
   // Do your stuff
}
```

And also remember that you need to do the insert operation under an AsyncTask.

Comment: So what do you recommend to do on the dao. Do i change the return type?

Comment: Yes. Remove the Single, just leave it as `fun load(): TutorialEntity?`

Comment: And also the single on the insert statement

Comment: Ok I will do that. 2 minutes

Comment: the insert statement should be returning Long our TutorialEntity?

Comment: The insert returns a Long always. If is -1 was not posible to insert.

Comment: So val load = tutorialDao.load() is giving me null

Comment: Should I do tutorialDao.load() ? @Hamlet Leon

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183595/discussion-between-jose-and-hamlet-leon).

Answer (score 1):

While you can do this using Room, it is suggested that you better not use Room for such operations. These kinds of single value checks are done using `SharedPreference`.
Quoted by Google [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences)

> If you have a relatively small collection of key-values that you'd like to save, you should use the SharedPreferences APIs.

With Room you have to consider creating `@Entity`, `@Dao`, call them in **background thread**. which are so much work

Here is how you do it with `SharedPreference`

```
val sharedPref = activity?.getSharedPreferences("AppPreference", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
```

And you check it as below

```
if (sharedPref.getBoolean("as_seen_tutorial", false)){
    // show tutorial. 
    // false is a default value
}
else{
    // start another activity
}
```

And after showing your tutorial, you save "as_seen_tutorial" as `true` like below

```
with (sharedPref.edit()) {
    putBoolean("as_seen_tutorial", true)
    commit()
}
```